# problema al usar context en react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, context

hola buenas como están tengo un inconveniente con el código de mi app estoy haciendo un e-commerce y para terminarlo me falta hacer que el shopping cart me agregue los productos al carro y se eliminen etc. pero el problema es que cuando quiero pasar los productos al carro me salen errores que iré compartiendo a continuación si alguien puede darme una mano agradecido estaré les comparto las siguientes capturas gente y gracias. Nota: esta es la primera ves que uso context.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en esa captura ese error aparece al hacer click en el botón del producto ahora paso las capturas de los componentes que del context y de donde renderiza esos productos a continuación.

```js
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const CartContext = createContext({
    cartItems: [],
});

const CartContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);
    const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get("http://localhost:3001/cart")
            .then((response) => {
                if (response && response.data) {
                    const { cartItems, totalPrice } = response.data;
                    setCartItems(cartItems);
                    setTotalPrice(totalPrice);
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }, []);

    const addToCart = (productId) => {
        const itemExists = cartItems.find((item) => item.productId === productId);
        if (itemExists) {
            setCartItems(
                cartItems.map((item) =>
                    item.productId === productId
                        ? {
                                ...item,
                                quantity: item.quantity + 1,
                          }
                        : item
                )
            );
        } else {
            axios
                .get(`http://localhost:3001/products/\${productId}`)
                .then((response) => {
                    const product = response.data;
                    const newItem = {
                        productId: productId,
                        id: uuidv4(),
                        src: product.src,
                        title: product.title,
                        price: product.price,
                        quantity: 1,
                    };
                    axios.post("http://localhost:3001/cart", newItem).then(() => {
                        setCartItems([...cartItems, newItem]);
                    });
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
        }
    };

    const deleteFromCart = (id) => {
        axios
            .delete(`http://localhost:3001/cart/${id}`)
            .then((response) => {
                setCartItems(cartItems.filter((item) => item.id !== id));
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    };

    const clearCart = () => {
        axios
            .delete("http://localhost:3001/cart")
            .then((response) => {
                setCartItems([]);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    };

    const updateTotalPriceInJSON = (totalPrice) => {
        axios
            .put("http://localhost:3001/totalPrice", {
                value: totalPrice,
            })
            .then((response) => {
                // console.log(response);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const updateCartItems = (newCartItems) => {
            setCartItems(newCartItems);
            const totalPrice = newCartItems.reduce(
                (total, item) => total + item.price * item.quantity,
                0
            );
            updateTotalPriceInJSON(totalPrice);
            setTotalPrice(totalPrice);
        };
        updateCartItems(cartItems);
    }, [cartItems, totalPrice]);

    const value = {
        cartItems,
        addToCart,
        deleteFromCart,
        clearCart,
        totalPrice: totalPrice,
    };

    return <CartContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</CartContext.Provider>;
};

export default CartContextProvider;
```

este es el cartContext!

y este es el componente del que yo quiero que se agreguen los productos al carrito!!

```js
import React from "react";
import Icon from "../assets/food.svg";
import { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import {
    Box,
    Box2,
    Box3,
    Box4,
    BoxBtn,
    BoxImg,
    Btn,
    Btn2,
    I,
    Img,
    Price,
    Text,
    Title,
    TitleImg,
} from "../styles/styledFoodMenu";
import AOS from "aos";
import "aos/dist/aos.css";
import axios from "axios";
import CartContext from "./CartContext";

const pic1 = require("../assets/product-1.jpg");
const pic2 = require("../assets/product-2.jpg");
const pic3 = require("../assets/product-3.jpg");
const pic4 = require("../assets/product-4.jpg");
const pic5 = require("../assets/product-5.jpg");
const pic6 = require("../assets/product-6.jpg");
const pic7 = require("../assets/product-7.jpg");
const pic8 = require("../assets/product-8.jpg");
const pic9 = require("../assets/product-9.jpg");
const pic10 = require("../assets/product-10.jpg");
const pic11 = require("../assets/product-11.jpg");
const pic12 = require("../assets/product-12.jpg");
const pic13 = require("../assets/product-13.jpg");
const pic14 = require("../assets/product-14.jpg");
const pic15 = require("../assets/product-15.jpg");
const pic16 = require("../assets/product-16.jpg");
const pic17 = require("../assets/product-17.jpg");
const pic18 = require("../assets/product-18.jpg");
const pic19 = require("../assets/product-19.jpg");
const pic20 = require("../assets/product-20.jpg");
const pic21 = require("../assets/product-21.jpg");
const pic22 = require("../assets/product-22.jpg");
const pic23 = require("../assets/product-23.jpg");
const pic24 = require("../assets/product-24.jpg");
const pic25 = require("../assets/product-25.jpg");

AOS.init({
    duration: 3000,
    easing: "ease",
    delay: 100,
    once: false,
    mirror: true,
});

const images = {
    pic1,
    pic2,
    pic3,
    pic4,
    pic5,
    pic6,
    pic7,
    pic8,
    pic9,
    pic10,
    pic11,
    pic12,
    pic13,
    pic14,
    pic15,
    pic16,
    pic17,
    pic18,
    pic19,
    pic20,
    pic21,
    pic22,
    pic23,
    pic24,
    pic25,
};

const db = require("../api/db.json");

const FoodMenu = () => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const addToCart = useContext(CartContext);
    console.log(addToCart);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get("http://localhost:3001/products")
            .then((response) => {
                setProducts(response.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }, []);

    const filterProducts = (type) => {
        if (type === "all") {
            setProducts(db.products);
        } else {
            setProducts(db.products.filter((product) => product.type === type));
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        filterProducts("all");
    }, []);

    return (
        <Box>
            <Box2 data-aos="fade-up">
                <I src={Icon} alt="icon" />
                <Title>Our Menu</Title>
            </Box2>
            <Box3 data-aos="fade-down">
                <BoxBtn>
                    <Btn onClick={() => filterProducts("all")}>All</Btn>
                </BoxBtn>
                <BoxBtn>
                    <Btn onClick={() => filterProducts("pizzas")}>Pizzas</Btn>
                </BoxBtn>
                <BoxBtn>
                    <Btn onClick={() => filterProducts("burgers")}>Burgers</Btn>
                </BoxBtn>
                <BoxBtn>
                    <Btn onClick={() => filterProducts("pasts")}>Pasta</Btn>
                </BoxBtn>
                <BoxBtn>
                    <Btn onClick={() => filterProducts("drinks")}>Drinks</Btn>
                </BoxBtn>
                <BoxBtn>
                    <Btn onClick={() => filterProducts("steaks")}>Steaks</Btn>
                </BoxBtn>
                <BoxBtn>
                    <Btn onClick={() => filterProducts("deserts")}>Deserts</Btn>
                </BoxBtn>
                <BoxBtn>
                    <Btn onClick={() => filterProducts("salads")}>Salads</Btn>
                </BoxBtn>
            </Box3>
            <Box4>
                {products.map((product) => (
                    <BoxImg data-aos="flip-left" key={product.id}>
                        <Img src={images[product.src]} alt={product.title} />
                        <TitleImg>{product.title}</TitleImg>
                        <Text>{product.description}</Text>
                        <Btn2 type="button" onClick={() => addToCart(product.id)}>
                            To Order
                        </Btn2>
                        <Price>${product.price.toFixed(2)}</Price>
                    </BoxImg>
                ))}
            </Box4>
        </Box>
    );
};

export default FoodMenu;
```

aqui dejo el archivo app.js tambien!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué tal si reemplazas el lambda por `function addToCart(productId) {`?

Comment: hola mateo te referís a que en ves de usar una función flecha lo cambie por una función normal?

Comment: Exactamenten eso.

Comment: lo probare gracias

Comment: Pon siempre el código y los mensajes de error _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes.

Answer (score -1):

El error de consola nos dice que addToCart no es una función, el código se ve bien, así que podríamos concluir que estamos invocando mal la función.
En el componente

```
const FoodMenu = () => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const addToCart = useContext(CartContext);
    console.log(addToCart);
}
```

En la constante addToCart estamos referenciando a todo el contexto, no específicamente a la función addToCart del contexto

Me parece que la constante deberia ser esta:

```
const FoodMenu = () => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const { addToCart } = useContext(CartContext);
    console.log(addToCart);
}
```

Extrayendo la funcion addToCart del contexto para poder usarla.

Espero sea la solución a tu problema, lo revise solo al ojo :(

Comment: hola como estas rodrigo eso ya lo he probado y no me funciona me da error y dice que no puede destructurar addToCart!